# How to access a TypeVariable's instance from a class decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm creating a class decorator but have some issues getting the typing right. Below is a minimal reproducable example which runs (no run-time errors) but lets pylance (using the static type checker pyright) complain.

My issue is, that `cls` in the wrapper function is `Type[T@wrapper]` (which in this example realizes to `Type[Base]`, not `Base`). This causes `cls.__init__ = init` to raise a pyright error `cannot be assigned to member "__init__" of class "type"`.

I tried to avoid using T instead of Type[T] throughout the Decorator definition which leads to the following pyright error:

```
Argument of type "Type[Base]" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "T@Decorator"
  Type "Type[Base]" cannot be assigned to type "Base"
    "Type[type]" is incompatible with "Type[Base]"
```

So it seems that Decorator's expect a Type and not a Type-instance. If that is correct, then the question is: How to access a TypeVariable's instance from a class decorator?

```
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar, Optional, Dict, Union, Generic, Type

class Base:
    def __init__(self, config: str):
        self.config = config    

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Base)

def Decorator(arg: str) -> Callable[[Type[T]], Type[T]]:

    def wrapper(cls: Type[T]) -> Type[T]:

        # remember original initializer
        _init = cls.__init__

        # updated initializer
        def init(self: T, config: str, *args, **kwargs):
            _init(self, config, *args, **kwargs)  
            setattr(self, arg, config)

        # set updated initializer
        cls.__init__ = init # <-------- type missmatch
    
        # return class with updated initializer and 
        return cls

    return wrapper


@Decorator('test')
class Test(Base):
    test: str

    def task(self):
        print("test module dummy task: ", self.test)
```

Although the code works as intended, having the described issue made me think if I took the right aproach here.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] if you are getting an error. Please post the full error message including the stack trace. If you are reporting something that comes from 3rd-party static analysis tools, *tell us*. Don't just call it an "error" because that implies a runtime exception. Is this error reported by mypy? pyright? your IDE?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The example I posted is a minimal reproducible example I created to demonstrate the underlying issue, let me know what you're missing. And yes, you're absolutely right, my 'errors' refer to errors reported by pyright (I thought this is obvious because I explicitly mention that the code works as intended implying no runtime errors). I modified my question to make this more clear!

Comment: I get an entirely different set of errors [when I run mypy on this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=02e817e8d2c09142a239b390df446416) (after fixing the missing imports).

Comment: Your code is missing a bunch of imports, it is not a [mcve]. This sounds like nitpicking, but it isn't. If you are going to ask a quesetion here, it is expected that people can reproduce it without having to fill in the blanks by running it, seeing it fail with other errors, fixing those and whittling it down to *what you actually are doing*.

Comment: Also, there are various third-party tools out there, `mypy`, `pyright`. You've said Pyright in these comments, but you say Mypy in the question. I think it is pyright. But again, don't make us guess. Why wouldn't you provide us with the information?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I dislike your tone; Why would you suggest I left that out on purpose? Copy & paste errors happen ;) Added the imports now. I also consistenly mention Pyright in my question (I think we can agree on the fact that the latest edid counts). I double checked that my example is reproducible in VSCode 1.76.2, python 3.8.16, Pylance v2023.3.20.

Comment: I also do not understand what the error you posted has to do with the code you showed here. Also, as soon as I replace your `cls.__init__` assignment with `setattr(cls, "__init__", init)`, there are no more type safety errors (by Mypy).

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg, thx for looking into this! It's less about the error itself; it's more about the fact that `cls` is of type `Type[Base]` during the decoration (I assume this comes directly from how @decoration works under the hood) and how to deal with this correctly when, as in my case above, overriding a function from that class definition (`Base` here).

Comment: Yes and no. `cls` _is_ any type `T` (i.e. has the type `type[T]`), with `T` having the upper bound `Base`. This means you can pass the class `Base` itself as the `cls` argument **and any subtype of `Base`**. When you decorate `Test`, `cls` is passed `Test`, which is a subtype of `Base`, so everything is correct there.